# Convert over 24Hr time into 24Hr time

Tags: excel, time

My data contains a row (A2:A40000) that contains accumulated hourly time. I am trying to convert it to 24 hour time, example: 24 to 0, 57 to 9 and so on.

Once that is done, I also want to get which day the time falls on, based on column A, assuming the first 0 starts on Monday 12:00AM, that would mean that Hr 24 will be Tuesday Hr 57 will be Wednesday and so on.

The end goal is to create a whisker chart with Day and time on X and column B on Y.

I would appreciate any help to get me started.

Example:

```
 A       B
0.00    0.00
1.00    0.00
1.00    0.00
2.00    0.00
12.00   2.00
14.00   0.00
16.00   0.00
17.00   0.00
17.00   0.00
18.00   0.00
19.00   10.00
22.00   0.00
23.00   0.00
24.00   1.00
26.00   0.00
28.00   0.00
46.00   0.00
58.00   0.00
10240.00    0.00
```

Comment: Have found a way to convert to 24 hours, "=(ABS((A2/24)-TRUNC((A2/24)))*24)". Now need to figure out how  to get the days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the hour of the day:

```
=HOUR(1+A1/24)
```

To get the weekday(Numerical)

```
=WEEKDAY(2+A1/24)
```

To get the Weekday(Name)

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(2+A1/24),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case to get hour of day, do 
`=HOUR(1+A1/24)`, you have to do +1 since you start with zero.

Hope this helps